# ZF2 force a anonymous user to log in or register

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Good evening.
I have two modules in my application - an Auth module, and an Album module. 
What i did - i added the means for a user to log in or register.
What i'd like to do - force any anonymous user to log in or register when he attempts to access any other actions.

All i did was save the user's data in the session variable like so:

```
//Zend\Session\Container;
$userSession = new Container('user'); 
$userSession->name = $username;
```

What i could do with this is i could verify at the beginning of every action of every module if there is any user data, but that would be too much copy/paste in my opinion. Is there a way to verify if the user is logged in in one place, and if not, just redirect him to the log in page without copypasting this in every action?

Comment: For a start, have a look at http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html#zend-mvc-controller-plugins-identity.

Comment: You want to redirect anonymous user to login page?